# Custom CSV imports into Mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import some csv data into mysql.  The problem is that there isn't an exact one-to-one mapping between the csv fields and the database fields.  I'm looking for an easy way to import data into just the fields needed.  I want to import some fields and not others.   One of the fields I want to assign a "2" to all cases in order to match a lookup value.

I could buy a tool but I don't want to spend the money.  Can I do this with my import command without having to edit the csv file?  Any examples or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

---------- desc addrTable; ------------------

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| supervisor  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lastName    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstName   | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fullName    | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| addr1       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| addr2       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city        | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state       | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zipCode     | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notes       | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| spouse      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender      | varchar(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| kids        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| birthday    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| spouseDOB   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| workPhone   | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cellPhone   | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

----------csv headers------------------

The following are my CSV headers.  Note that some of these headers don't have values '*'d' and I want to skip these fields?  Also there is no supervisor field.  That is a lookup and I want to assign the value of '2' to every single imported record.

```
"Last_Name",
"First_Name",
"Full_Name",
"Address",
"City",
"State",
"Zip",
"Notes",
"Spouse",
"Kids",
"Birthday",
"Birthday_Day", *
"Birthday_Month", *
"Spouse_DOB",
"Email",
"Work_Phone",
"Cell_Phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would load the data using mysqlimport into a temporary table.... then select from the temp table to into the destination. That way you can add the missing column.

e.g:

```
insert into t2
select last_name,first_name, etc,2 as supervisorid
from t1
```